# Is it possible to change names of Doxygen generated html files?

Tags: doxygen

We are going to publish API documentation on our web site. The documentation is generated by Doxygen from sources. The problem is that Doxygen generates weird file names (which is not so good for SEO). For example, for the source file `RO4_Languages.h`, Doxygen generates `_r_o4___languages_8h.htm`.

Is it possible to change name of generated files? I realize it's possible to change output using third-party tools/scripts (awk/sed/perl/etc), but I'm hoping to do it entirely through Doxygen

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145278/making-stable-names-for-doxygen-html-docs-pages

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know changing the name of the generated files is not possible in Doxygen. I don't feel that the HTML output of the Doxygen is designed to be SEO-aware.

So if you really want to change the names, you should use the 3rd party tools you've mentioned.

Comment: i have also been looking for something along these lines, but I want it to stop creating random filenames every time its regenerated. even without changing the comments and running doxygen again all the filenames change, many files are named like /d2/d82/classAppModel_a2818fd177783671c8ca6b93284769f86.html which never stays the same.