# Making stable names for doxygen html docs pages

Tags: doxygen

I need to refer to Doxygen documentation pages. The file names however are not stable as they change after every generation. My idea is to create a symlink to each  HTML file created by Doxygen , having a stable and human friendly name. Have anyone tried this?

Actually, it might be very easy just to parse the annotated.html file Doxygen produces. Any documented class shows up there as a line like:

```
`<tr><td class="indexkey"><a class="el" href="dd/de6/a00548.html">
ImportantClass</a></td>`
```

The hard problem for me is that I would like to have my file names (i.e. the symlinks) be visible on my server like:
    http://www.package.com/com.package.my.ImportantClass.html

[Yes, the code is in java]. So the question actually reads: "how to connect a HTML page by Doxygen with the right java class name and its package name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to have SHORT_NAMES enabled, which will indeed produce volatile names. When you set SHORT_NAMES to NO in the configuration file (the default), you will get longer names, but these are stable over multiple runs (i.e. they are based on the name, and for functions also on (a hash of) the parameters.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I still consider making the stable symbolic links as I proposed since this would give nicer file names. Of course it would be easier to link to the stable HTML file names. In meantime  I decided that the easiest file to parse would be the tagfile prepared by doxytag